# Laravel Framework - Video not showing through Laravel, works when I go directly to the file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel Framework.
The code that I am trying to fit into the application is : http://pastebin.com/gX4zSP7B

The video in the script plays perfectly normal when I go to "localhost/film/laravel/app/views/test.php (I've also used test.blade.php)" although when I go to test.dev the video does not work.

I know that the file location is right, due to the  working.

I tried to modify the file to work with Laravel framework : http://pastebin.com/CcbM1F3E

Both don't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Toby.

Comment: one of your links doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have the folder media inside the folder public?

Comment: @user1305626 No, I just have it sitting in my view folder.

Comment: @user1305626 Works! Thanks! I did not realize files had to be in the public folder, I thought it was relative to the file. Answer solved.

Comment: @user2957677 The `app/views` folder should never be exposed to the server root. Only assets within the `public` folder would ever be accessible to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel you should have the media folder inside the public folder on the root of your application (as soon as you have not modified it anywhere)

You can also check the view-source with is the link generated for your video. (Using inspect element)